# Start line with `\eqref`

Tags: line-breaking

My collaborator highlighted all lines starting with an eqref and asked me to avoid this by placing a `~` between the reference and the preceding word. For example, he suggested replacing `it follows from \eqref{ref}` with `it follows from~\eqref{ref}`.

I get that a reference of the form `Theorem \ref{thm}` should be written as `Theorem~\ref{thm}` to avoid the line break between `Theorem` and its reference, but I'm not convinced about the above case. Is it a general rule that lines should not start with a reference to an equation?

Comment: I generally does not see an issue with it. I tend to follow a rule where something short + punctuation shouldn't start a line, in which case the `~` is handy. I'd say this rule seems more of a house rule whan a general rule of thumb.

Comment: It is enforced in my part of engineering. Apparently it can be mistaken for part of a numbered list rather than an equation reference.